ESP32 hardware serial port receives junk characters
I have two ESP32 boards connected back to back through a serial cable, using pin 16 for Rx and 17 for Tx. They exchange simple hello world messages through the serial2 hardware port on the ESP32. The received messages are echoed on the regular serial port 0, so that I can monitor them on the PC through an USB cable.
There are no other connections to the boards except the Rx and Tx pins, and the USB cable connecting to the PC.
This test is in preparation for a larger project, where one board will send command messages through the serial2 port and the other will execute them.
This is an outline of my test program:
String str;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  while(Serial2.available()) {  
    str = Serial2.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(str);
    Serial2.println("OK);
  }
}

The sending side is even simpler:
void loop(){
  Serial2.println("Hello world");
  delay(4000);
}

The program works fine, and messages are sent and received accurately. But unfortunately, when one board is yet to initialize,
the Serial port on the other board spits out lot of random characters like K⸮}⸮⸮⸮KK⸮-mo⸮⸮m⸮⸮[K⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮
Once the sender is initialized and starts sending out regular messages, the garbage vanishes and regular messages are displayed.
I tried reducing the baud rate to 9600, connecting the ground pins of the two boards through a wire, etc. But so far the junk print out has not vanished. This will be dangerous in my main program, since random messages can operate unintentional relays and trigger other unwanted actions. Please suggest some ways to isolate the issue.
Edit: I placed a delay before initializing the serial port at the sending end:
delay(10000);
Serial2.begin(115200);

The receiver is dumping garbage characters, non-stop, during these 10 seconds!
NOTE: I am surprised at the negative vote; I am not asking for a workaround for my problem; I have already solved it by using simple error correction techniques. But I am raising it here as a warning to all future serial port users, so that we can collectively try to understand the problem.
I am only trying to understand why the ESP32 behaves in this unexpected way. I have also raised it as a bug in the ESP32 Git repository.

Presumably the commands you're sending follow some sort of structure, so validate the incoming data to ensure that it matches that structure and discard the rest. You could add a CRC as well. You should be doing this anyway to guard against bad commands. You should probably add some positive response to indicate that a command has been received or discarded.

wire ground between boards. and you can add pull-up resistors to hold the pins HIGH while the MCU initializes

@Tangentially Perpendicular, this was the only saving grace. I send a string like "MAY DAY!" at the beginning of transmission. The receiver looks for this string  in the data stream and starts processing only after seeing this marker. But my concern is, why an uninitialized serial port should spew out so much of garbage like a volcano! Such an unruly behavior can make the system unstable at any time.

"But my concern is ..." - The serial port is a link to an external, unmanaged device. You have to be prepared for the worst (E.G. no response, untimely response, disconnect) and have robust software. On the other hand, I have never seen what you describe when properly grounded, and signal connection have proper pull-ups to hold line at MARK level.

@sawdust : Thanks. But Isn't a digital output expected to directly drive another digital input, provided the voltage levels are compatible? My connecting wires are just 2 inches long. I can understand scenarios like no response/disconnects etc, which is part of any communication protocol. But an output pin being in an undefined state at boot up till the software initializes it- is this a normal design practice? Once I call Serial2.begin() on the sender, then there is absolutely no noise.

What you call a "digital input" is really a simple ADC. See https://superuser.com/questions/1092952/is-dsl-digital-or-analogue/1093013#1093013 Not sure about ESP32, but Atmel SoCs I work with require the pin to be first multiplexed to a peripheral, and then that peripheral would enable (i.e. drive) that output. Until then, that pin may float unless there is a pull-up or -down. Additionally on both sides, you have to configure the UARTs, and common practice is to then discard the input buffer. A robust receive program would never assume there's always clean/perfect input.

@sawdust, I see your point. Since I am not in a position to cut the PCB tracks and install pullup resistors, I have taken your advice to ignore all input till the system stabilizes. Knowing for sure when the input is stable is not mathematically guaranteed, but I will go by common world standards!

The developers have replied that the serial pin will be in an undefined state before it is initialized. So I have put a work around in software: I just ignore all characters before a known marker is received. This works well for me, for now. But this is only sweeping the problem under the carpet.
Probability theory says that if sufficient number of monkeys type randomly for sufficient number of years, then you can expect to see a quote from Shakespeare in their output!
For the benefit of future readers of this page facing a similar issue, here are some other practical remedies:

Put the serial pin on the sender to INPUT_PULLUP mode at the very beginning.
Put the serial pin to OUTPUT mode and write a 0.
Introducing a 2 second delay at the start of the receiver program worked in my case.

Hardware based solutions that may work as well:

Using external pull up/pull down resistors on the serial line.
Out of band signaling: Use the RTS/CTS pins on ESP32 serial port (or any other digital pins) to communicate readiness between the sender and receiver.


Some systems/protocols have used the break condition to perform a signal to the other end. Sending a break condition is typically rather easy, but receiving notification that there was a break condition is often difficult/awkward. The app can sometimes configure the serial interface to inhibit/ignore any break condition (e.g. the IGNBRK attribute in POSIX termios).
